# TableView Height Wrapping (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, tableview

Am having little items in my Table View but am facing a challenge the TableView doesn't automatically wrap it's height according to the items in it, the TableView is long but having little items ,  how can i tackle this. Below is my XAML code :

```
<TableView Intent="Form" x:Name="sales_tableView" RowHeight="-1">
            <TableView.Root >
                <TableSection Title="Agent Sales Details">

                    <TextCell Text="Agent Number" x:Name="agentNumber_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple"   />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Rating "  x:Name="agentrating_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple"/>
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Phone "  x:Name="agentphone_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Email " x:Name="agentemail_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple" />

                </TableSection>
            </TableView.Root>
        </TableView>
```

EDIT:

**This is the Screen shot :**

[image: The Image]

Comment: Could you provide a quick screen shot of what it's doing? might give us a better idea of what constraints the control is/may be using to position the text.

Comment: i have provided the screen shot , check the distance between the TableView and the button , the TableView isn't wrapped  automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well regarding this problem , this is how i tackled that , what i noticed is if you set the `HeightRequest` of a TabelView with ranges from `0,1,2 and above`, the TableView height will still be long , so i just set the `HeightRequest` with values from `0,-1,-2,...`

**So below is my Code sample :**

```
  <TableView Intent="Form" x:Name="sales_tableView" RowHeight="-1" HeightRequest="-2">
                <TableView.Root >
                    <TableSection Title="Agent Sales Details">

                        <TextCell Text="Agent Number" x:Name="agentNumber_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple"   />
                        <TextCell Text="Agent Rating "  x:Name="agentrating_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple"/>
                        <TextCell Text="Agent Phone "  x:Name="agentphone_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple" />
                        <TextCell Text="Agent Email " x:Name="agentemail_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple" />

                    </TableSection>
                </TableView.Root>
            </TableView>
```

Hope this helps , **Happy Coding**

Comment: this code works like charm , amazing idea , was still stack. Thanks @Lutaaaya

Answer (score 0):

So you could simply add a static ViewCell to the bottom of your table that contains your button and hooks up as normal to the click method in the code behind, and then set the background to transparent.

```
<TableView Intent="Form" x:Name="sales_tableView" RowHeight="-1">
            <TableView.Root >
                <TableSection Title="Agent Sales Details">

                    <TextCell Text="Agent Number" x:Name="agentNumber_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple"   />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Rating "  x:Name="agentrating_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple"/>
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Phone "  x:Name="agentphone_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple" />
                    <TextCell Text="Agent Email " x:Name="agentemail_txtcell" DetailColor="Purple" />

                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Text="MY CLIENTS" Clicked="MyClickMethod" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>

                </TableSection>
            </TableView.Root>
    </TableView>
```

I think you can just set the background colour in the XAML, i think you just add this property

```
BackgroundColor="Transparent"
```

to the xaml of the tableview, but I can't quite remember if that's right, either way you can do the same thing in the code behind:

```
sales_tableView.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableView Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="true">
```

Notice: HasUnevenRows="true"

Comment: let me try it and see